# MS Excel 2010 Create Shape Object Name with Formula

Tags: excel, vba

In MS Excel 2010:

How can I change the Name of a Picture object by linking it to a cell.

Right now I have:

```
Sheets("Tabname").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 72
Selection.Name = "New Name"
```

to name the new object "New Name"

What I would like to be able to do is name the new object by linking to a cell

I tried:

```
 Selection.Name = "=C306"
```

but I didn't get the contents of the cell but rather my new object was named *=C306*

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Selection.Name = Range("C306").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Selection.Name = Sheets("Tabname").Range("C306").Value
```

to set the value of that particular cell on that particular worksheet

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks for the help!